# Limit of recursive sequence (help for getting the nth term expression)

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I am trying to find the limit of this sequence (I was able to verify that it is a Cauchy sequence), but I am having problems finding the expression for the nth term.

### $a_{n+2} = \frac{a_n+3a_{n+1}}{4} $

with  $a_0=0,    a_1=1$

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know anything about generating functions?

Comment: Hmmm I don't think so. Apparently I should be able to solve this using induction only. I studied chapter 2 of Bartle-Sherbert Real Analysis ... but couldn't figure out how to solve this

Answer (score 1):

**Hint (which almost gives the full solution).**

You have $$a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n+3 a_{n+1}}{4}-a_{n+1}=-\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{4}$$

from there you can compute $a_{n+1}-a_n$ based on $a_0,a_1$ and finally $a_n$.

Answer (score 1):

For all integer $n\geqslant 0$, we have
$$
  a_{n+2} - a_{n+1} = -\frac{1}{4}(a_{n+1} - a_n).
$$
The sequence $(b_n)_{n\geqslant 0}$ defined by $b_n = a_{n+1} - a_n$ is
geometric with common ratio $-1/4$ and first term $b_0 = 1$, so
$b_n = (-1/4)^n$. Now,
$$
\begin{align*}
  a_n = a_n - a_0 
      = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (a_{i+1} - a_i) 
      = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(\frac{-1}{4}\right)^i 
      = \frac{4}{5}\biggl(1 - \Bigl(\frac{-1}{4}\Bigr)^n\biggr)
\end{align*}
$$
for all $n\geqslant 0$.